# Using temporary objects to do some tasks like log writing a good idea?

Tags: c++

So I was searching for a good way to make a log manager to use in my programs, and I found an article, with a class similar to this(I simplified it to a few lines of code just to show it here) :

```
class Log
{
public:
   Log();
   virtual ~Log();
   std::ostringstream& Get();
protected:
   std::ostringstream os;
};
std::ostringstream& Log::Get()
{
      return os;
}
Log::~Log()
{
   //  Write the data from ostringstream;
}
```

The log record is written in the destructor, so to write a log record, you do this:

```
Log().Get() << "Log record";
```

It's a temporary object, so the log record would be written when this object is destroyed. Is it ok to do it like this ? Is this a better way than using a singleton ? 
Article with the class can be found [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/logging-in-c/201804215)

Comment: Is the question about temporary objects or about singletons?

Comment: where did you find the article? Can you provide a link?

Comment: The question is about the performance of using a log object like this, each call to Log, means a new temporary object. There is a link at the end of the question.

Comment: Actually I do not understand the design. It basically is just an `ostringstream`. Putting it in a class is rather meaningless imho. There is no point in having the stream hidden as a protected member, when anyway a reference is leaking to the public interface. I do not see any benefit of using this logging class over a plain `ostringstream`.

Comment: I think that the point being is that you can manage later what to do with the data in the ostring strea: Save it to a file, output it on screen, etc.

Comment: @tobi303 The point of the class is to buffer up the log message data (which may be multiple stream insertions), then dump it to the *real* log file as a single hit via the destructor, using a `std::osringstream` as the buffered container of the IO source. The benefit you're not seeing is without this scheme, the *caller* would have to do dump-to-string-stream, then dump the final IO to the real log file, which is probably synchronized (or at least it better be).

Comment: @WhozCraig hm yes, I guess I misunderstood, because the part that really does the job (dumping in the constructor) is not shown in the snippet. Still I find the question rather confusing, because this class can be used as temporary as well as singleton, or am I wrong again? ;)

Comment: The point is to string outputs together. `QDebug` does this well. `qDebug() << "i=" << 42 << "meters";` results in `i= 42 meters\n` which lets you pretty print stuff without having to worry about formatting. The `operator <<` inserts a space and the destructor inserts a newline.

Comment: @tobi303 you wouldn't use *that* class as a singleton. It would never dump the log until destruction, which for most singletons is either EOP (end of process) or even never if it is a dynamic expected shutdown leak. As-written it is designed to use scope lifetime to dictate when the final dump happens to the "real" log target in the destructor.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks, I think now I got it. I would say it just depends on how the logger is supposed to be used. If log messages are written frequently to the same file I would go for a singleton, while if the logger is only used rarely using temporaries might be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A temporary object is destroyed at the end of the expression in which it is created. So yes, it will write/log info in a timely manner.

The drawback of this approach is that each time you create the temporary, you'll create and then destroy a stringstream (and eventually a filestream to log it).  This seems an important performance overhead ! So I'd say that a singleton would be a better approach.

The advantage of a long living logger (be it singleton or not), is that you could optimise the logging overhead (e.g. write immediately to a file, or accumulate the data and write it periodically, especially in high performance sections of your code, where realtime disk i/o would slow down too much the execution).

***Edit/Additional infos***

The overhead of temporary creation/destruction including streams shall not be under-estimated.  I ran [this informal benchmark](http://ideone.com/CcnSTE) on my PC with 100 000 small log entries (MSVC release mode):

- 48 second for the temporary based logger
- 1 seconds for the permanent logger.

It compares your temporary logger (including a file write in the destructor) to 
a (very) simplified permanent one:

```
class Log2
{
public:
    Log2();
    virtual ~Log2();
    std::ofstream& Get();
protected:
    std::ofstream os;
};
std::ofstream& Log2::Get() { return os; }
Log2::~Log2() { }
Log2::Log2() : os("log2") { }
```

By the way, there are some nice logging frameworks around. [This tiny one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/584794/Simple-logger-for-Cplusplus) is very simple one.  It can have several instances (so not a singleton), which permits also modular loging.

Comment: Thanks :) I know that the temporary object is destroyed at the end of the expression, but not sure how efficient it is, I never seen anyone until now writing code like this, so I'm not sure how big the overhead would be, and if this style of coding should be used.

Comment: @Silencer the overhead for a `std::ostringstream` isn't hideous. One place you may get bit by this is a memory-allocation failure by the stream object while buffering up the output data, especially when logging an out-of-memory exception catch handler (ouch). By that time you're already in bad company so that may not be something currently on your radar. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig :) I was talking more about the overhead of creating a lot of objects. And if the destructor writes to file, things get a lot uglier, reopening same file increases the execution time of the program.

Comment: @Silencer the performance overhead is significant (some informal measurements show a factor 50 between the two approaches).  I've added some benchmarking infos to my answer.

Comment: @Christophe Thanks for such a complete answer :) Tried to upvote your comment, but it doesn't show cause I don't have the "reputation" :) The high execution time for the temporary logger should be mainly because of the reopening of the file, I am not sure why opening a file takes so much time, I was able to cut the execution time of a program working with txt files in half, just by keeping a file open, instead of reopening it a few thousand times :)

Answer (score 0):

stringstream buffer is not guaranteed to provide an infinite length buffer. So if you use this log class, possible chance of missing earlier log info before writing into a file.  Otherwise if you intend to write logs intermittently , you are going to create and destroy  log objects again and again. It will definitely guarantee a performance hit.

So singleton implementation of log class should choose against this one.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine in this situation. Also, it is acceptable to use constructor/destructor pair to log entry and exit from a function for debugging. All you do is create an instance of the object as first line in function. Contructor logs the entry into the function and destructor(called automatically as part of stack unwinding when function returns) logs exit from function.